# Magento; Display more products per page in one category

Tags: magento

I have the site set to display 3 items per page and I would like to set only one category to display all items in one page. Any help would be appreciated. I tried the solution suggested in [Product grid 4 columns and certain pages 5 column with two rows of full products, how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5426893/product-grid-4-columns-and-certain-pages-5-column-with-two-rows-of-full-products) and it didn't work for me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Chesky

Answer (score 0):

Each category has it's own handle. So for example for category with id 10 you will have

```
category_10
```

handle.

SO I suggest to write a specific handle and custom template or layout updates.

```
<category_10>
    ....<!-- Here you should specify template which will show all rpoducts or specify custome layout xml settings. -->
</category_10>
```

Comment: Well this should be local.xml, or in admin, if I don't mistake each category has layout updates field.

Comment: I see now that my xml update from the custom layout is adjusting the category accordingly. The problem is that it only shows the change when I navigate to the category. I however have the category set to NOT display on the navigation menu, instead it loads a slider that is displayed on the bottom of the home page and category pages. Is there a way to have the slider display all the products even if the rest of the page is displaying only three per page?

Comment: my problem is solved in the following thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854110/magento-limiting-number-of-returned-items-in-product-collection-call